# How to add more data to a field

Tags: entities

I'm trying to find the best way to extend a field's data set (not even sure of the right terminology).

What I want, is to attach some other information to an existing field. Let's take a file field, called "my_file", and attach some "other" information to it.

The end result should be, when using `node_load` and `entity_metadata_wrapper`, I can get the "other" value.

So these code snippets should give me the value:

```
$node = node_load($nid);
return $node->field_my_file['und'][0]['other'];
// And this should work:
$wrapper = entity_metadata_wrapper('node', $node);
return $wrapper->field_my_file->other();
```

I'm not that familiar with the Field API, so if you can point me in the right direction that'd be good.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hm, if I understand you correctly you want to extend a fields schema. As far as I know, there is no easy way of doing this, e.g. there is no `hook_field_schema_alter()`. And the way that comes into my mind to achieve this is rather complicated and involves a lot of different hooks and logic that seems just bloated and error prone.

Instead I would recommend to create a new field type module based on the one that you want to extend, then alter this so that it suits your needs. Obviously this should only be done if you are still in the development phase of your site. If there is already any content this could do more harm than good, because you would need to migrate the content.

Another way, little elegant, but certainly possible is to create your proper storage solution for the information that you want to attach to the field(s) in question, meaning providing custom database tables and implementing the hooks described in [field.api.php](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!field!field.api.php/7) that you need for your use case.

Comment: Using a custom table seems like the way to go then.

Answer (score 0):

All this will work if you add the [Fields](https://drupal.org/documentation/modules/field-ui) to your Drupal Nodes.

You may add the `Fields` to your content type (a Node) as a administrator at the following url of your site: `/admin/structure/types/manage/NODE_TYPE/fields`

**EDIT**

read up on an [Introduction to Entities](https://drupal.org/node/1261744) in Drupal 7.

Comment: I want to add additional information to existing fields. That is the question.

Comment: a single `Field` is 1 piece of information. `Entities` are made up of 0 or more `Fields`. ... some fields like `Field_collection` are really entities which can be attached as fields to yet other entities. You cannot add "additional info" to existing fields -- it doesnt work that way. You _can_ make a `compound field`, but I doubt that is what you want. Find a combination of `Fields`, `field_collections`, mayyybe Relations from the `relation` communinity module that meet your needs.